# REST error 400 "Access Denied" on IE11

Tags: reactjs, rest, internet-explorer, http-headers, axios

We're facing the problem with REST Api on Internet Exploler.

Evety single request is blocked by the browser. The same requests works correctly on other modern browsers. When we add our our application to trusted pages, it starts working. It is only possible solution?

On **api.domain.com** we have Slimp PHP framework with backend. 
On **www.new.domain.com** we have new webpage and in some cases we're connecting with REST Api and it works correctly even on Internet Exploler.

The problem occurs on subdomain **app.domain.com** with React-Redux frontend app with axios library for REST connection. We're using 2 custom headers: *x-accept-language* ( overrides accept-language on Edge/IE ) and *x-authorization*.

Request infomation:

```
URL: https://api.domain.com/user/login
Request method: OPTIONS
Code: 400 / Bad Request
```

Request headers:

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, x-accept-language, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 0
Host: api.newpastoral.net
Origin: http://localhost:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

Response headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization, x-authorization, x-accept-language, accept
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS,POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: close
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 10 Jan 2018 08:10:04 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
```